# Auto-update .NET Franmwork version to 3.0 or 3.5 before the installation of application on client PC

Tags: .net, frameworks, auto-update

My application is based on.NET Framwork 3.0. Like when i installed some PC games, is there any solution of simple way to update client PC's .NET Framework automatically before the application is installed? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

in `setup project` set in `prerequisites` to install `.net framework 3.5` from vendor website.
Then while installing new version setup will check if `.NET 3.5` exists and if not, will install it.
Here is screen from Setup Project Properties http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/3698/setupmu.jpg